# How to manipulate JSON in php?

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

Suppose I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"tag":[{"Item1":"Required"},{"Item2":"Not Required"},{"Item3":"Maybe Required"}]}
```

And I am posting this from volley to my server that receives JSON objects like this:

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Say I am suppose to check whether or not, item2 is received? How do I do that?

I tried this:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');// Assuming $json looks like: {"tag":[{"Item1":"Required"},{"Item2":"Not Required"},{"Item3":"Maybe Required"}]}

$temp=$json["tag"];// assuming $temp would look like: [{"Item1":"Required"},{"Item2":"Not Required"},{"Item3":"Maybe Required"}]

$temp1=$temp[1]["Item2"];//assuming $temp1 looks like: "Not Required"

$data=array();

$temp2=array('Status'=>$temp1);// assuming $temp2 looks like ["Status"=>"Not Required"]
array_push($data,$temp2);

$response=array('phpStatus'=>$data);// assuming $response looks like: ["phpStatus"=>["Status"=>"Not Required"]]

echo json_encode($response);// Assuming encoded version should look like: {"phpStatus":[{"Status":"Not Required"}]}

?>
```

Note: The assumed encoded json is exactly what I want to receive in android!

```
{"phpStatus":[{"Status":"Not Required"}]}
```

Comment: You'll need a call to `json_decode` if you want to work with it, otherwise you're on the right track

Comment: @iainn Can't I directly manipulate received JSON?

Comment: No, it's just a string until you decode it. `file_get_contents` will retrieve a string from the request, then call `json_decode` to convert this string into a PHP data structure. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @iainn Sure I am trying that right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is only a string when you pull it with file_get_contents, so you need to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the JSON string to access values.

When you decode the string, your JSON data is now an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [tag] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Item1] => Required
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Item2] => Not Required
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Item3] => Maybe Required
                )
        )
)
```

Here is a short working snippet:

```
 $json_in = '{"tag":[{"Item1":"Required"},{"Item2":"Not Required"},{"Item3":"Maybe Required"}]}';

 // Decodes JSON into an associative array.
 $JSON = json_decode($json_in, true);

 // Displays data neatly for you to see the structure of the array.
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($JSON);

 // Retreive Item2
 $item2 = $JSON['tag'][1]['Item2'];

 if ($item2 === "Required")
     {
     echo "is received";
     } else
     {
     echo 'is not received';
     }
```

Comment: @VidorVistrom no problem at all glad it helped.